# The Events Calendar - Datepicker not working

Tags: the-events-calendar

The dropdown datepicker is throwing a not found error. I am not sure if this is a 3.2 issue or not, because I did not install this plugin until after the 3.2 release, but I know the datepicker is a jQuery function, so it might be.

You can view the error here:

Sample error for datepicker choice of August, 2011:
http://hammondmarina.com/wp/category/events&eventDisplay=month&eventDate=2011-08
(Select the "Events Calendar" from the main menu to get to the grid. New here so I can't post more than 2 links in this post.)

The forward and backward links are working fine. I discovered that when you substitute the "&" with a "?" after category/events, the link will work:
http://hammondmarina.com/wp/category/events?eventDisplay=month&eventDate=2011-08

How do I fix this in the the-events-calendar/views/datapicker.php file or the template-tags.php file (where references to the datepicker both occur)?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the plugin settings and make sure 'Use Pretty URLs' is set to on. This fixed the issue for me.